# EF Code First DbContext and Compiled Queries

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, linq-to-entities, entity, code-first

Has anybody heard if there is any word on whether we will have compiled queries with EF Code First DbContexts?  Or, if it is already possible, and I am doing it wrong, can somebody point me in the right direction?  It would seem Bing and Google don't have a lot of information on it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CTP4 had compiled query support, but it was removed in CTP5, vote it up if you want it back here:
http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1379241-bring-back-compiled-queries-in-code-first

and/or here:
http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1012355-automatic-compiled-queries?ref=title

Comment: I thought that was the case and am really disappointed.  Thanks a ton for sharing those links.  I went and gave 3 votes to each of them.  I really hope they bring them back.